# How can I add an onmouseover event to a line?

Tags: c3.js

Using c3.js, I have a line graph with many lines. The tooltip properly appears at individual data points, and I can use the mouseover property to fire on data point hover.

I need to change the color of a line on the graph on mouseover at any position of the line. It appears as though lines are obscured from hover events by other shapes as I can't even get pain JS or CSS to fire events. Is there any way to get c3.js to fire an event when the mouse moves over and out of a line?

Answer (score 0):

It's a default js function method calling:

```
onmouseover: function () { ... }
```

Comment: From what I remember, the issue is that other elements are layered on top of the lines, so the onmouseover event does not fire.